# running local html in wkwebview - no javascript

Tags: javascript, swift3, wkwebview

I am trying to get a mobile webpage in an iOS app. Unfortunately the web view is not executing any javascript. After googling a while it turns out that apple restricts local javascript. 
Any suggestions how to make it work anyway?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController ,WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView : WKWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let webView = WKWebView()
    let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Webpage/index", ofType: "html")
    let htmlUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!, isDirectory: false)
    webView.loadFileURL(htmlUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlUrl)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
      }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}


// WKNavigationDelegate

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Loading")
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Loaded")
}
```